# cv2 counting dense objects

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and learning this with python. I was trying to count number of objects in an image using thresholding, eroding, overlaying functions and it was successful, but this technique does not work when objects in an image are very dense and background can hardly be seen. For that problem I am thinking to define a specific size for an object and to count the number of foreground areas that can hold that size, but I do not know how to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you you can do it with finding and concatenate **[contours](http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html#table-of-content-contours)**. for example this is a snippet that cal area of a rectangle !

```
area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
rect_area = w*h
```

for an object like this:

For example with this code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('star.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
cnt = contours[0]

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)

for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
    start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
    end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
    far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
    cv2.line(img,start,end,[0,255,0],2)
    cv2.circle(img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

you have a result like this :

[image]

and also you can use **[Corner detection](http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html#harris-corners)**  with Harris or a [fast corner detection](http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html#fast) !